# What kind of transformation is space translation?

Tags: terminology

Translation of a point in space with position vector ${\vec r}$ by a fixed vector ${\vec a}$ leads to a new vector $$\vec{r}^\prime={\vec r}+{\vec a}$$ which, is not strictly a linear transformation because it does not send zero vector to zero vector. Do mathematicians have a name for such transformations?

Comment: It's an affine transformation.